# Logback: selectively masking statements and prudent mode

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

We are using the `%replace` function of Logback to mask security sensitive information such as passwords and security tokens in our log files.

However, only a 10% of the log statements targeted to a specific appender require masking. For the remaining 90%, running the replacement regex is a redundant overhead.

We have thought of using Markers such as `SEC_SENSITIVE` to tag sensitive statements, and using a Filter to restrict which appenders are run. This would require setting up 2 mutually exclusive appenders for a single logger.

```
Logger
  |---- Appender 1 (only if marker != SEC_SENSITIVE, no replacement)
  |---- Appender 2 (only if marker == SEC_SENSITIVE, with replacement)
```

Both appenders write to the same file.

Having arrived at this point, I have several questions:

1. Does this set up make sense? Or is there a simpler way? (ideally OOTB, with no custom code)
2. Documentation and StackOverflow questions about the `prudent` option emphasise its usage for multiple JVM setups. In our case, all logging output will originate in a single JVM. Is it still necessary to enable this option? Or is Logback clever enough to synchronize 2 *local appenders* outputting to the same file?
3. Is there an OOTB Filter for this? I only found [MarkerFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/MarkerFilter.html), but it's a `TurboFilter`.
4. Are conditional replacements now supported OOTB (as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624952/1970990))?

**Environment:** OSGi on Apache ServiceMix with Pax Logging 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work. Don't forget the additivity=false.

Alternatively, wouldn't it be easier to stop the problem at the root and, in the toString of the object, redact any sensitive fields?

Sometimes sensitive cases are not so easily spotted, such as Tokens, or SAML Subjects, and these too should be redacted from the logs.

Comment: I'm not dealing with POJOs, but with serialized representations already, e.g. XML, JSON, etc. So there's no quick way to achieve the masking at the calling code. Furthermore, in such a scenario I'm interested in using async appenders to avoid affecting the application's performance with the processing of logs.