# How to 'censor' some data in libraries self-generated logs?

Tags: scala, logging, logback

I am using the library  scalikejdbc for my Application. And when i read the logs, that scalikejdbc generates itself, it gives me something like that:

```
06:02:16.891 [main] DEBUG scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$ - Registered connection pool : ConnectionPool(url:jdbc:sqlserver://foo.bar:8080;databaseName=foobar;user=user;password=**PASSWORD**;...
```

So scalike itself throws my database user's password into the logs, which is inappropriate.

I was thinking about filtering those logs at all with something like https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html , but I do need the odd information from those logs from scalike, so I cannot filter them fully.

What do I have now:

```
06:02:16.891 [main] DEBUG scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$ - Registered connection pool : ConnectionPool(url:jdbc:sqlserver://foo.bar:8080;databaseName=foobar;user=user;password=somepassword;
```

What am I try to get:

```
06:02:16.891 [main] DEBUG scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$ - Registered connection pool : ConnectionPool(url:jdbc:sqlserver://foo.bar:8080;databaseName=foobar;user=user;password=CENSORED;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624952/5205022) conversion word in `logback.xml` configuration, for example,

```
%replace(%msg){"password=.*", "password=CENSORED"}
```

which given

```
logger.debug("password=123456")
```

should output something like

```
[debug] application - password=CENSORED
```

[Docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace) state

> **replace(p){r, t}** Replaces occurrences of 'r', a regex, with its
>   replacement 't' in the string produces by the sub-pattern 'p'. For
>   example, "%replace(%msg){'\s', ''}" will remove all spaces contained
>   in the event message.

Here is an example of my `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %replace(%msg){"password=.*", "password=CENSORED"}%n %xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```